# Target function does not assign to class attribute when called by multiprocessing.Process from within Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, multiprocessing

Consider the following code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.out = []

    def fit(self, x):
        for i in x:
            self.out.append(i*i)

test = Test()
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I call `test.fit()` using `Process` form `multiprocessing` in an Jupyter Notebook like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

p = Process(target=test.fit, args=(X,))
p.start()
```

My problem here is, that even though `Process` calls `test.fit`, the product `i*i` is not appended to `test.out`. If I replace `self.out.append(i*i)` by `print(i*i)`, I get the desired result. Hence, the calculation is done. If I call `test.fit(X)` without `Process`, `test.out` is append as desired. What am I doing wrong here?

Using Jupyter 4.4.0 on macOS 10.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the GIL, Python cannot share the memory with subprocess, basically. In order to share the memory with subprocess, I think you need to use `multiprocessing.Queue`.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.out = Queue()

    def fit(self, x):
        for i in x:
            self.out.put(i*i)

test = Test()
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

p = Process(target=test.fit, args=(X,))
p.start()
p.join()
```

Then, get values from queue.

```
y = []
while not test.out.empty():
    y.append(test.out.get())
print(y)
```

---

Added@2017/12/02

Another way using to create `shared list` via `multiprocessing.Manager` is here. I think this is what you originally tried.

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process, Queue

manager = Manager()

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.out = shared_list = manager.list()

    def fit(self, x):
        for i in x:
            self.out.append(i*i)

test = Test()
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

p = Process(target=test.fit, args=(X,))
p.start()
p.join()

print(test.out)
```

Comment: I added another implementation pattern which relies on `multiprocessing.Manager`.